# Defining a pair of cofixpoints by mutual corecursion

Tags: coq

Is there an easy way define two cofixpoints in a way that lets you output both of them at the same time? Ideally I would like something like the following:

```
Require Import Streams.

Definition alts : Stream bool * Stream bool :=
  cofix a := Cons false b with
        b := Cons true a for (a,b).
```

However, it seems that Coq only allows you to return one of the identifiers from a block of mutual cofixes.  The best I can do right now is the following:

```
Definition alts2 : Stream bool * Stream bool :=
  let a := cofix a := Cons false b with
                 b := Cons true a for a in (a,Cons true a).
```

Of course, this is not ideal because I need to then repeat the definition of `b`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but still: `CoFixpoint a : Stream bool := Cons false b
with b : Stream bool := Cons true a.
Definition alts : Stream bool * Stream bool := (a, b).`. Would you prefer to avoid polluting the namespace?

Comment: @AntonTrunov No that works for me, I hadn't realized that you're allowed to reference `b` outside of the definition of `a` like you've done.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use `CoFixpoint` to mutually define `a` and `b` and then reuse those to define `alts`.

```
CoFixpoint a : Stream bool := Cons false b
with b : Stream bool := Cons true a.

Definition alts : Stream bool * Stream bool := (a, b).
```

The downside of this approach is that we pollute the namespace with new names `a` and `b`.